# Project organisation - File path and folder default naming

Tags: optimization, coding-style, organization

I'ld like to organize my coding and projects better. Are there any folder-name and file-name defaults I should use or are there any preffered ones within the industry?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Coding C++ most of the time, I organize my folders according to the namespaces my classes reside in, under a global src/ folder. I mix header and source files, although I know a lot of people that keep headers and sources separate in src/ and include/ folders. I think this is rather a thing of preference - I see the advantages of both approaches.

My filenames are typically the same as the classes the source file belongs to - (at least) one source file per class. For non-class code, I try to organize the functions/data according to logical units with "speaking" names.